# SQL Methods Function to add "Gold Medal" for anniversary

Tags: oracle, functions

I'm trying to create a method function on SQL using Oracle Developer.

The member function will give employees a gold medal after 12 years of service to the bank, a silver medal after 6 years of service and a bronze medal after 2.

The issue I am having is with the pre-defined `date_type` that I have in my `employee_type` which is as follows

```
CREATE type employee_Type
AS object(
    name name_type,
    supervisor REF EMPLOYEE_TYPE,
    position VARCHAR2(20),
    salary   NUMBER(5),
    ninum    VARCHAR2(8),
    joindate DATE);
```

And below is the Method I'm trying to implement

```
    ALTER type employee_type ADD member FUNCTION give_medals
  RETURN string CASCADE;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY employee_type
AS
  MEMBER FUNCTION give_medals
  RETURN STRING
IS
BEGIN
  IF self.join_date > 12 THEN
    RETURN 'Gold Medal';
  ELSIF self.join_date = 6 THEN
    RETURN 'Silver Medal';
  ELSIF self.join_date = 2 THEN
    RETURN 'Bronze Medal!';
  END IF;
END give_medals;
END;
```

But again my issues is lies with the `ELSIF` statement, as you can see I'm returning a Gold Medal for anything over 12 - but because the date_type is like `01-JAN-98` everything in the join_date value will be given a gold medal.

So how could I change the function to give Medals for years of service instead of just anything `>` 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume that the fact that you're using `join_date` with an underscore in your code while the type uses `joindate` is a typo.  Otherwise, you'd get a compilation error.

You want to calculate the difference between `join_date` and the current date.  My guess is that you want to use `months_between` to calculate the number of months between the two dates and build your logic based on that.  `months_between` probably does what a human wants when he or she says "12 years" but date arithmetic gets tricky particularly when things like leap days are involved (if you joined on Feb 29, 2016, do you hit your 2 year mark on Feb 28, 2018?  Or March 1, 2018?).  If you need to account for time zones, that makes the logic more difficult.

```
IF months_between( sysdate, self.join_date ) >= 12*12
THEN
  RETURN 'Gold';
ELSIF months_between( sysdate, self.join_date ) >= 6*12
THEN
  RETURN 'Silver';
ELSIF months_between( sysdate, self.join_date ) >= 2*12
THEN
  RETURN 'Bronze';
ELSE
  RETURN null;
END IF;
```

Comment: Hi Justin, Yes that correct `join_date` is a typo. 

Yes the employee will hit the 2 year mark on the 28th of Feb 2016 if they started on the 29th Feb 2018. This is what I Am looking for! How Would I access the function? Like so? 

`SELECT* FROM employees e where e.give_medals = 'Gold Medal';` @JustinCave

Comment: @Scott - What is the `employees` table?  Are we talking about the table in the HR schema?  Or one that you created?  Is it an object table?

Comment: No the `employees` table is my own. Along with the `employee_type` it is an object relational table which has references to other tables and nested table for phone numbers that belong to the `employees` @JustinCave

Comment: @Scott - I'm not sure that clarified anything for me.  It sounds like you want to ask a new question and post a reproducible test case (at a minimum, the table definition, the full object definition, your sample data, etc.)

Comment: Here is a link to me new question [Query produces wrong results for SQL Member Function](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143639/query-produces-wrong-results-for-sql-member-function)